# Problem on system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Is it possible to solve a system of equations with 3 variables knowing just 2 equations? I'm trying to figure out if it is possible/how, but I failed so far.
$$
\begin{cases}
0,2x+0,3y+0,1z=0,35(x+y+z)\\ 
x+y+z=5\end{cases}
$$
i also know conditions
$\begin{cases}0\le x\le6\\ 0\le y\le2\\ 0\le z\le8\end{cases}$

Comment: Hint to "is it possible to solve this knowing just these two equations": **No**. What you'll get is an infinite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, in this case a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

it's depend what you call "solving". You will not get 3 scalar values for x,y,z, but you will get a relation between them. For a linear system it will be of dimension 1.

Interpretation: this system tells that (x,y,z) belong do 2 different planes.

Comment: im not familiar with english in math , could you elaborate? how could i  get the relation between them? I have only solved system of equations with 3 equations

Comment: These 2 equations are equation of 2 planes. (x,y,z) obeying these 2 equations at the same time means than (x,y,z) is on the intersection of 2 planes,  i.e., a line. The relation between x, y and z is the relation relying coordinates living on a line. In 2D you could write it as a line equation. In 3D you write it on a parametric way: $(x,y,z) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)+t(dx,dy,dz)$, or $\frac{x-x_0}{dx}=\frac{y-y_0}{dx}=\frac{y-y_0}{dx}$.

Comment: i have updated question , i know conditions to this , would it make any simplier? im quite lost right now